# Sending array through post jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I now this question has been asked before but I am trying to work this out since this morning and I can't get it right.

I have a global variable named items

I have a .ajax request that I need to send the contents of the items array

Items is like this

```
items = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   //just populating the list
   var item = [];

   item['some_stuff'] = 'string';
   item['some_int'] = 373;

   items.push(item);

}
```

//here is the request

```
    if (items.length > 0)
    {   
        $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "/grad1/adaugaComanda.php",
                data : { "stuff" : items},
                success : function (data){

                    alert(data);
                //  window.location = '/dashboard.php?categ=5&sel=1';

                }
                });
    }
```

//

The request is executed but data is not sent. I tried to use JSON.stringify on the array but it returns empty ([[]]).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You'll need to define the array as `var item = {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   //just populating the list
   var item;
```

This declares a variable called `item` but does not give it a value to it so it is `undefined`

```
   item['some_stuff'] = 'string';
```

This attempts to assign a value to the `some_stuff` property of `undefined`. This isn't allowed, so JS will throw an exception and script execution will cease.

You aren't making a request at all, because your script isn't getting far enough to do that.

You need to assign an object to `item`:

```
var item = {}
```

---

You have edited your question so your code now reads:

```
var item = [];
```

You still need to use a plain **object** here (`{}` not `[]`). `Array` objects should only have *numeric* indexes. jQuery will ignore named properties on an array when serializing it.

Comment: Is there a way I can convert the array into a object ?

Comment: @ring0 — *possibly*, but I'm not certain and all the potential approaches I can think of are horrible. You really should use an object in the first place. An array is simply the wrong data structure to use in the first place.

Comment: i think `var item = new Array();` will also work.

Comment: @Manwal — No. It **won't**. Named properties on arrays will **not** be serialized.

Comment: Thanks man it really gave me a headache. The internet is full of missleading information including stackoverflow.

Comment: Horrible hack — `var foo = [];
foo.bar = "testing";
var bar = {};
for (var p in foo) { bar[p] = foo[p] };` will create an object with the same properties as an array, you might still trip over the prototype chain, I had no luck in converting an array to an object — you should still use an object in the first place for named keys.